# Linux distro sought which will install on older 32-bit PC without PAE

Tags: linux, installation, linux-distributions, pae

I want to put Linux on a older 32-bit laptop without PAE; it has Windows 7 now.

When I try to install my favorite distro, that fails and tells me the PC's CPU lacks PAE support.

How may I find a Linux 32-distro which does not demand PAE?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/888285/up-to-date-distros-supporting-32-bit-i586-non-pae-specifically-for-alix-boards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answer at https://serverfault.com/questions/888285/up-to-date-distros-supporting-32-bit-i586-non-pae-specifically-for-alix-boards , and this question is poorly written

Answer (score 0):

[Bodhi Linux](https://www.bodhilinux.com/) has very minimal [requirements](http://www.bodhilinux.com/w/system-requirements/) without PAE, as does [antix](https://antixlinux.com/about/) (their [requirements](http://download.tuxfamily.org/antix/docs-antiX-19/FAQ/index.html#_system_requirements)) .